# Data Binding like Behaviors with Unity

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

To summarise my meandering question in one sentence before I explain the problem. How can I make it so that if I update a value from a key in my Dictionary, it will fire the OnPropertyChanged method associated with that key/TextBinding, or should I be doing this a different way

I have some experience with WPF/MVVM Databinding so the dream solution is for my project: if a value in my game changes, it will automatically update anywhere where it is currently displayed on the UI.

I've got a very rudimentary place to start with using a dictionary lookup table but there may be some folks who understand what I need that will work better

The First block of code is the BindingBehavior that can be regarded as attached to the UI text field (a component of the same parent game object to be a little more precise)

If I set TextBinding to a value my UI changes to reflect it, but if I change a value via my dictionary it seems to be that my dictionary only holds a copy of the value assigned to it at that time, and does not update the reference "TextBinding"

EDIT:I lost a block of text somehow, patched

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class BindingBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string BindingName;
    public string TextInitialValue;

    private string _textBinding;
    public string TextBinding
    {
        get
        {
            return _textBinding;
        }
        set
        {
            _textBinding = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(value);
        }
    }

    void NotifyPropertyChanged (string value)
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = value;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        TextBinding = TextInitialValue;
        UIManager.Instance.BindingLookUp.Add(BindingName, TextBinding);
        Debug.Log (BindingName + ", " + TextBinding + " was added to Binding Lookup Dictionary");
    }
}
```

> Below is the separate class for readability

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class UIManager 
{
    private static UIManager _instance;
    public static UIManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new UIManager();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
        set
        {
            _instance = value;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> BindingLookUp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

EDIT: Second Attempt using a class from some suggestions read elsewhere on stack overflow (reference type?) still does not seem to be doing the job.

```
public class BindableString
{
    private string _stringValue;
    public string StringValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _stringValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _stringValue = value;
        }
    }

    public BindableString(string s)
    {
        StringValue = s;
    }
}

public class BindingBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string BindingName;
    public string TextInitialValue;

    private BindableString _textBinding;
    public BindableString TextBinding
    {
        get
        {
            return _textBinding;
        }
        set
        {
            _textBinding = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(value);
        }
    }

    void NotifyPropertyChanged (BindableString str)
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = str.StringValue;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        TextBinding = new BindableString( TextInitialValue);
        UIManager.Instance.BindingLookUp.Add(BindingName, TextBinding);
        Debug.Log (BindingName + ", " + TextBinding + " was added to Binding Lookup Dictionary");
    }
}

public class UIManager 
{
    private static UIManager _instance;
    public static UIManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new UIManager();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
        set
        {
            _instance = value;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, BindableString> BindingLookUp = new Dictionary<string, BindableString>();
}
```

And this is the call I am making to update the Text

```
UIManager.Instance.BindingLookUp["ActiveCharacterActionPointsRemaining"] = new BindableString(_activeCharacter.actionPointsRemaining.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have a solution I am happy to work with at the minute for Text binding though I will be taking it to the Unity Answers site to see if there's a way to do a more generalized version of the Dictionary using gameobjects or components or something that would be a much more 'stable' solution. Here is the code. In hindsight it seems so obvious I don't know why I tried this first.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class BindingBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string BindingName;
    public string TextInitialValue;

    public Text TextComponent;

    public string TextValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (TextComponent == null)
            {
                TextComponent = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
            }
            return TextComponent.text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (TextComponent == null)
            {
                TextComponent = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
            }
            TextComponent.text = value;
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        TextValue = TextInitialValue;
        UIManager.Instance.UITextBindings.Add(BindingName, TextComponent);
    }
}

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class UIManager 
{
    private static UIManager _instance;
    public static UIManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new UIManager();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
        set
        {
            _instance = value;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Text> UITextBindings = new Dictionary<string, Text>();
}
```

and to update the UI text I need to simply make a call

```
UIManager.Instance.UITextBindings["ActiveCharacterActionPointsRemaining"].text = _activeCharacter.actionPointsRemaining.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to implement your own `ObservableDictionary` class that fires the `PropertyChanged` event with the `PropertyName` set to `"Item[]"`.

There is a sample implementation here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/. The key parts are:

```
private const string CountString = "Count";
private const string IndexerName = "Item[]";
private const string KeysName = "Keys";
private const string ValuesName = "Values";

private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add)
{
    if (key == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

    TValue item;
    if (Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out item))
    {
        if (add)
            throw new ArgumentException("An item with the same key has already been added.");
        if (Equals(item, value))
            return;
        Dictionary[key] = value;

        OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value), new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, item));
    }
    else
    {
        Dictionary[key] = value;
        OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }
}

private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> changedItem)
{
    OnPropertyChanged();
    if (CollectionChanged != null)
        CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, changedItem));
}

private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> newItem, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> oldItem)
{
    OnPropertyChanged();
    if (CollectionChanged != null)
        CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItem, oldItem));
}

private void OnPropertyChanged()
{
    OnPropertyChanged(CountString);
    OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
    OnPropertyChanged(KeysName);
    OnPropertyChanged(ValuesName);
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: I am getting a problem with the following line             /t/t/t/t               public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged                                  /t/t/t/t it looks like in my using System.ComponentModel it is not bringing in INotifyCollection changed and there is no option to resolve it, what is it I need to do to get it to find INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: You need to reference the `System.ObjectModel` assembly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: I 100% had that reference in but I've moved from trying to hold the  string from changing the dictionary from <string, string> to <string, Text> where Text is an instance of the UnityEngine.UI Text class. Seems to work so far so I guess I'll just try to make different binding behavior classes to work with Text, Images, Sliders etc. Thanks for your help!